Clustering two-dimensional data in R
I have 35 linear models in a data frame (b is intercept, a is coefficient):
xy <- structure(list(b = c(2045.08, 2045.58, 2045.33, 2045.29, 2045.39, 
1991.67, 2053.54, 2048.3, 2049.76, 2003.74, 2021.51, 1984.74, 
2038.64, 2053.64, 2011.17, 2039.31, 1891.7, 1745.42, 1712.83, 
1119.93, 1097.59, 1629.34, 1638.34, 1038.81, 1673.84, 1663.97, 
784.72, 885.24, 1800.33, 1723.93, 1017.47, 1014.38, 1651.5, 2969.72, 
3254.87), a = c(2.48, 2.36, 2.42, 2.43, 2.4, 3.67, 2.29, 2.41, 
2.38, 2.69, 2.55, 2.84, 2.47, 2.35, 2.68, 2.52, 3.4, 4.33, 4.53, 
8.05, 8.18, 4.94, 4.89, 8.51, 4.7, 4.76, 9.94, 9.36, 4.04, 4.48, 
8.63, 8.19, 4.82, -1.94, -2.52)), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")

Some of them are very similar and I would like to reduce the amount of models by clustering.

Data look like highly correlated.
I have tried kmeans() but it produces many clusters for dense clouds of points and one cluster for visually separated points.
kmeans(xy, 12)$centers |> points(pch = 3, col = "red")


It can be seen that all b values less than 1500 have only one cluster. The same is for two high b values. And visually dense cloud of b values around 2000 is separated into several clusters.
Is there any other method of clustering such data?
Edit: 3 clusters is not enough in my case. My goal is not to average data but to discard similar data.

Why do you fix the number of clusters as 12? I'd expect k-means with k=3 or even 4 to deliver something reasonable here.

@ChristianHennig, This was just an example. Even such high number does not work as I expected.

So did you try k-means with 3 clusters and nstart=100 (see comment to answer by @StephanKolassa)? If so, what do you think of the result?

What were the original 25 models from?  What were the datasets / variables?  What was the goal of fitting those models?  It doesn't seem like we're asking about the right point in the analysis plan.

k = 3 doesn't work good in my case. The original models are automatically detected trends for stock data. The goal is to visualize most important trends while omitting similar lines. Currently it is like this: 

Why doesn't k=3 work well?  It looks like the obvious solution.

@gung, please take a look at the comment above yours. 3 trend lines is not enough and of course they cannot be averaged. I need to discard some of them.

I don't understand why you need to cluster these at all - they are so strongly correlated, it looks like it can be summarised with a single intercept and slope.

@mkt, No, slope is changing from -2 to +10 (please see the plot which I provided). It cannot be summarized into one LM

Yes, but that variation from -2 to +10 is very strongly correlated with variation in the intercept. So the variation in the plot can be described with a slope and intercept (maybe you could argue that the lowest two points are a little different). But with an explanation for why clustering is a worthwhile goal here, I don't think there's much to be said.

There are lots of clustering methods for Euclidean data. One thing that should do OK here is average linkage hierarchical clustering (using the Euclidean distance). This will produce a hierarchy of clusters. You could use the Average Silhouette Width to decide a number of clusters. (It'll quite certainly say 3 here.) R-functions hclust with method="average", and silhouette in package cluster. There are many more.

Thank you for your answer. Could you please share the list of methods that may be useful in my case? I would like to test them all.

@Stasik Sorry, there are hundreds of new clustering methods published every year. To just name a few, the hclust function also allows you to fit single linkage, complete linkage and Ward, there's spectral clustering, Gaussian mixture model-based clustering, partitioning around medoids, dbscan and many more. I don't think you'll get much out of throwing all of these at a data set with 35 observations.

@Stasik Probably the best option would be to construct a tailor-made clustering method specifically for this, involving a model for how the underlying linear models relate to each other, so that you can use the background of your data. I don't think any automatic method will be good at estimating the number of clusters without that. But chances are this would be too much work to be done by strangers on the internet for you for free.


kmeans(xy, 12) pre-specifies 12 clusters, that is far too many for just 25 data points.

If you don't specify the starting cluster centers, k-means will set them randomly. It's usually good to re-run it multiple times and see what happens.

I personally prefer DBSCAN to k-means. It also has control parameters (which method doesn't?), but it tries to detect the optimum number of clusters, and has a notion of points outside all clusters.



"but it tries to detect the optimum number of clusters" - I don't see any benefit of "detecting the number of clusters" if this requires to set another tuning parameter instead (that normally is harder to interpret than the number of clusters itself). Ultimately both k-means and dbscan need a (formal or informal) comparison of different results with different tuning choices (in k-means the number of clusters itself) to decide the number of clusters.

Also dbscan has an essentially different cluster concept from k-means, so the first thing to ask deciding about them is whether you rather want convex clusters with similar within-cluster variation in all directions and centroid object, or whether you want density-based clusters that allow for arbitrarily large within-cluster distances. (That said, for the shown data with k=3 and suitable dbscan tuning they may give the same or very similar solutions.)

By the way, re item 2, for the TO it may be added that the nstart parameter in kmeans sets the number of algorithm initialisations. nstart=100 should give good results here. The fact that as a default nstart=1 is one of the most stupid things in R.

Thank you. I've specified 12 clusters just as an example that it didn't work as expected. My ultimate goal is to create unsupervised script to clean up (reduce actually) any amount of linear models. Now I am researching how can I accomplish that. Of course, I've re-run kmeans many times but the results are very different

@ChristianHennig Excellent idea about nstart=100! Now it is much better! Now I need to figure out how to determine number of clusters automatically

@Stasik If what for you is a good clustering depends crucially on the meaning of the data and what you want to use your clustering for, chances are standard automatic criteria (such as average silhouette width or gap statistic) will not give you what you want, as they will only use the data and not the additional information that is important in your case. This will hold for whatever automatic clustering method and whatever criterion you use.
